# Spring: Nested beans reference to another bean is not working

Tags: java, spring

I am trying to use nested beans with a profile to setup an embedded jms broker when I am in dev mode. Here is my xml:

```
<beans ...>
... 
  other bean definition
...           
    <beans profile="embeddedBroker">
            <!-- Configure an embedded ActiveMQ Broker with a TCP connector.
                 This broker is never set to start automatically by default, it is the broker service wrapper that
                 will take care to start it if configured to do so.
            -->
            <amq:broker id="jmsBroker" brokerId="EmbeddedBroker" brokerName="EmbeddedBroker"
                        persistent="false" useJmx="true" start="false">
                <amq:plugins>
                    <!-- lets enable detailed logging in the broker but ignore ConnectionEvents -->
                    <amq:loggingBrokerPlugin logMessageEvents="true" logConnectionEvents="false"/>
                    <amq:timeStampingBrokerPlugin zeroExpirationOverride="1000" ttlCeiling="60000" futureOnly="true"/>
                    <amq:traceBrokerPathPlugin />
                </amq:plugins>

                <!-- Create a connector to give an external remote access to this broker. -->
                <amq:transportConnectors>
                    <amq:transportConnector uri="tcp://127.0.0.1:35000" />
                </amq:transportConnectors>
            </amq:broker>

            <!-- This broker service (wrapper) control the lifecycle of the jms broker defined above.
                 By default the internal broker will be initialized, but not started. It will usually be started only for
                 internal integration and unit tests.
            -->

            <bean id="jmsBrokerService" class="com.imetrik.global.common.jms.AMQBrokerService"
                  init-method="start"
                  destroy-method="stop">
                <property name="broker" ref="jmsBroker" />
                <property name="enabled" value="true" />
            </bean>
        </beans>

    </beans>
```

But when I run my application with the correct profile, spring complain that the jmsBroker reference cannot be found!

```
Error creating bean with name 'jmsBrokerService' defined in class path resource [jms-beans.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'jmsBroker' while setting bean property 'broker';
```

Is there a way to fix that? Is it because the reference bean is not in the same namespace?
I know that if I put it out of the nested beans, it is working fine.
I am using Spring 4.1

Comment: Do you _maybe_ have to qualify it with the profile name?

Comment: qualify what? The amq:broker?

Comment: The bean reference name `ref="embeddedBroker.jmsBroker"`. (This is a huge guess.)

Comment: It'll have to be in EL @SotiriosDelimanolis: `#{embeddedBroker.jmsBroker}`, if at all possible

Comment: Thanks but this is not working...